# get array of waveform off an audio track

Tags: android

I want an array of the waveform of the current audio track. I now do this by using a visualizer and listen for the onWaveFormDataCapture in the visualizer.

Now is there a way to get the complete waveform of the audio track so I could do something with it before playing the song?

Comment: @ i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280535/java-mp3-inputstream-to-byte-array) post. Might be just what you needed.

Comment: Mm not exactly but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the audio track in .wav format, you can just use [`Files.readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to achieve this.

> Read all the bytes from a file. The method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been read or an I/O error, or other runtime exception, is thrown.

Because the wav format is just the wavefrom. Read format specification [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)

Comment: I get the songs via streaming. So they need to stream wav. Else I need to convert this to wav?

Comment: @user1007522 How exactly do you receive the audio? Maybe there is an easyer way.
And please include the into your question that you recieve the track from a stream for better awnsers

Comment: I get them via an audio stream in MP3.

Comment: @user1007522 mp3 is a compressd format. That will be more difficult to decode,  but I'll search for a solution